# Json.NET JsonConvert.SerializeObject type is not compatible

Tags: c#, json.net

When trying to serialize an object using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject)`, I get the error

```
Error getting value from 'Payload' on Namespace.Request.

Type specified in JSON 'Namespace.Request.Payload, Server.Merged, Version=1.0.0.123, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<token A>' is not compatible with 'Namespace.Request.Payload, Server.Merged, Version=1.0.0.456, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<token A>'. Path '$type'.
```

As you can see, the types are the same. The only thing that changes is the BuildNumber of the type version. The assembly was merged before using ILMerge.

I am wondering how this check is done. I have tried setting `TypeNameHandling` to `None`, but it did not help. I would expect such a check to happen on deserialization, but why does it fail on serialization?

We already fixed the issue using a workaround (delete all Nuget Packages and Re-Add them). It appears to be an issue with the Visual Studio Package handling, where it was always using the old package. But I am still interested in understanding the JSON part anyways.

Comment: Post your code, although the error seems pretty clear - your projects use different assemblies for that type and you should ensure they both use the same type. If you added that type through a NuGet package, you should upgrade it.

Comment: Did you read the last paragraph?

Comment: Yes I did. The assemblies are mixed up. Without any code or even the full exception text it's not possible to go deeper - where did the type come from, how come it had a different build number (separate projects?, different compilation times/). Which method threw and why? Are there any inner exceptions that explain what's wrong? A lot of that information is contained in the exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()` - that emits the call stack and all inner exceptions

Comment: The different build number came because Visual Studio was not updating the dependencies correctly. My question is why does this error (which, yes is obvious) happen during *serialization*. Why does it even check two assemblies? Where does it store the second assembly? I would understand this error happening during deserialization, but not serialization. And how can I turn off this behavior?

Comment: Without any information, not even the serialization code, configuration or exception text, one can only guess. You're asking how your solution, using ILMerge to merge one assembly into another, ended up somehow using different versions. It could be that the build order of the two assemblies was merged and the serialization code ended up trying to call a type version when the merged assembly contained another one. Perhaps the master project was built first and the merge step rebuilt and merged a newer version. Or the opposite.

Comment: In any case, the full version string matters, not just the major and minor numbers. That's typically not an issue as [.NET can automatically add binding redirects to app.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions#relying-on-automatic-binding-redirection) in some cases. In your case though it seems that app.config doesn't contain those redirects